# How to tell which git branch is checked out?

Tags: git, github

I have a project on github and I just committed and pushed it. However, my changes don't show up on github.

I think I didn't have the `master` branch checked out. Which means I don't know the name of the branch I'm currently working in. Honestly, I don't really know where I just committed my changes.

How can I find out which branch I currently have checked out? How can  merge these changes into `master`? What did I just do?

When I committed, it said:

```
 # Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
 # with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
 # Not currently on any branch.
```

And then I did a `git push`, and I have no clue where that was pushed to.

```
$ git log

commit dcb85bcfafa18d9dfe9f12659e7ba0e2662ca45e
Author: ...
Date:   Wed May 18 22:41:57 2011 -0400

    Fix for new vm website layout, add CREDITS
```

Where is my code? How can I merge it into master?

Comment: May I suggest watching [this gitcast](http://blip.tv/scott-chacon/git-talk-4113729), it helped me a lot when I first started using git.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
git branch
git branch --contains dcb85b
gitk --all --date-order
```

To merge it into master, you could `git merge dcb85b` or `git cherry-pick dcb85b` or one of any number of commands.

Comment: @poundifdef: I recommend the http://progit.org Pro Git book.  Also highly recommended is http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/ Git for Computer Scientists

Comment: Try gitref.org before Pro Git... it's a very nice intro that covers all the basic command you'll need.

Comment: Might this return multiple branches if they all include the same commit from previous merges?

Comment: @PaulHodges: Yes, for the second command you will get all branches that contain that commit.  Using `gitk` might help you understand which is the branch you want.  Also note, you can *create* a branch at the commit in question if you want that commit but not a more recent one.